# is there any possibility to use async/await with map,

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async function I have to call it under the map function,

```
class DataArticle {
id:number,
title:string,
...
user:User // User Entity 
}
```

I want to get articles then assign to each article the author of it:

```
var dtresult = this.articleRepo.findAll(); // get all articles 
const result:DataArticle[] = dtresult.map(async (a:DataArticle)  => { 
let user = await this.UserRepo.getUser(a.id)
a.user = user ; // assign user to the article after getting the user 
return a ;
 })
```

I tried implemeting async function with this way and it doesn't work

Comment: Change `async dtresult.map(a:DataArticle  => { ` to `dtresult.map(async a:DataArticle  => { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use another library for this task.

It can be achieved by [`Promise.All`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled))

```js
async function getUser(id){return id;}
let data = [...Array(10).keys()]


async function the_caller_function(){
   const result = await Promise.all(data.map(async a=> {
      let user = await getUser(a)
      return {user:a}
   }))
   console.log(result)
}

the_caller_function();
```